# updating html content with XMLParser

Tags: html, groovy, html-parsing

I try to update anchor tag from html content in file with groovy XmlParser :

```
String fileContent = new File('//' + url.toString()).text
    page = new XmlParser(new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()).parseText(fileContent)
    page.'**'.A.grep { anchor ->
        anchor.attribute('href') != null && !anchor.'@href'?.startsWith('http') && !anchor.'@href'?.startsWith('ftp:') && !anchor.'@href'?.startsWith('mailto:') && !anchor.'@href'?.startsWith('attachments')
    }.each { anchorToReplace ->
        anchorToReplace.'@href' = getTitleFromUrl(anchorToReplace.'@href')
        println(anchorToReplace.'@href')
    }
```

and page.text() doesn't have updated content. what's wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an XmlBuilder to generate XML. The XMLParser only parses XML.

```
def xmlBuilder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{ mkp.yield page }
xmlBuilder.toString();
```